# Python Pandas: drop duplicate rows (keep only first row) based on same id and same date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| id | seen | year | month | day | dayname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| f907942e330ac3653f8a9bd655770872 | 2021-06-02 16:34:56 | 2021 | 6 | 1 | Monday |
| 042b60106231fa8a8e43dd750432d5bc | 2021-06-02 16:13:29 | 2021 | 6 | 1 | Monday |

The ID column has repeated values, due to the fact that it creates an entry when a user enters a building and a second one when it leaves it.

**What I want to do is delete all the repeated id values for each day**. For example, a person can go to that building on monday 01/01/2021 and again on wednesday 01/03/2021, given that, 4 entries are created, 2 for monday and 2 for wednesday, I just want to keep one for each specific date.

As you can imagine, I've tried things like `df_filtered = df.sort_values(["seen"]).drop_duplicates("id")` but it doesn't work for me as it deletes ALL of the duplicated values across the dataframe.

How can I drop the duplicated ID's (and their respective rows) on each single day without affecting the other days?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about grouping it by everything but `seen` and keeping the first record, that is - `df.groupby(["id", "year", "month", "day"]).first()? you can reset the index afterwards

Comment: Just tried it. Didn't work. Also removes some ID's entirely from other dates.

Comment: You can drop duplicates by multiple columns: `df.sort_values(["seen"]).drop_duplicates(["id", "year", "month", "day"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try group by `id` and the date only (without time) of column `seen` using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) + [`dt.normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html), and use [`GroupBy.first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) to get the first entry of each group, as follows:

```
# Optionally convert to datetime if not already in datetime format
df['seen'] = pd.to_datetime(df['seen'])

df.groupby(['id', df['seen'].dt.normalize()], as_index=False, sort=False).first()
```

**Demo**

**Data Input:**

(Added some rows for more comprehensive testing):

```
df

                                 id                 seen  year  month  day    dayname
0  f907942e330ac3653f8a9bd655770872  2021-06-02 16:34:56  2021      6    2     Monday
1  f907942e330ac3653f8a9bd655770872  2021-06-02 17:54:56  2021      6    2     Monday
2  042b60106231fa8a8e43dd750432d5bc  2021-06-02 16:13:29  2021      6    2     Monday
3  f907942e330ac3653f8a9bd655770872  2021-06-04 16:22:56  2021      6    4  Wednesday
4  f907942e330ac3653f8a9bd655770872  2021-06-04 17:43:56  2021      6    4  Wednesday
```

**Output:**

```
                                 id                 seen  year  month  day    dayname
0  f907942e330ac3653f8a9bd655770872  2021-06-02 16:34:56  2021      6    2     Monday
1  042b60106231fa8a8e43dd750432d5bc  2021-06-02 16:13:29  2021      6    2     Monday
2  f907942e330ac3653f8a9bd655770872  2021-06-04 16:22:56  2021      6    4  Wednesday
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

#Your Data frame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':['f907942e330ac3653f8a9bd655770872','042b60106231fa8a8e43dd750432d5bc'],\
                 'seen':['2021-06-02 16:34:56','2021-06-02 16:13:29'],
                 'year':['2021','2021'],\
                'month':[6,6],'day':[1,1],'dayname':['Monday','Monday']})
```

#Use drop_duplicates

```
df_nodups=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id','year','month','day'])
```